# Query language for python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, filtering

I have a list of python dictionaries (let's assume each dict is flat for the time being). The keys are all strings and the values are strings or real numbers. I would like the user to have the freedom to filter this dict in which ever way they choose to, using some kind of query language. The query can contain nested 'and's and/or 'or's.

What would be the best way to implement (or preferably re-use) a language/sytax which I can execute safely inside the application (an unsafe option would be to use eval)?

for eg:

```py
list_of_dicts = [
    {"type":"a", "val1": 10, "val2": 12.2, "val3": "off"},
    {"type":"b", "val1": 230, "val2": 15.5, "val3": "on"},
    {"type":"c", "val1": 40, "val3": "off"},
    {"type":"a", "val1": 60, "val2": 52.0, "val4": 12},
    {"type":"c", "val1": 80, "val2": 18.1},
]
```

The user should be able to say:

"Give me all items where type is a or b. From the resulting list, give me all cases where val3 is off"

Which translates to:

```
cond = lambda x: x.get("type") in ["a", "b"] and x.get("val3") == "off"
resultant = [a for a in list_of_dicts if cond(a)]
# Out: [{'type': 'a', 'val1': 10, 'val2': 12.2, 'val3': 'off'}]
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is answerable as written.  There's no 'best' syntax; just those fit your needs and those that don't.  If you narrow it down to looking for an existing syntax, that might be answerable.  But don't use eval(), please.  We should have all learned that lesson from the Log4Shell debacle.

Comment: It need not be best. Just wanted to know if there is any reasonable way.

Comment: Absolutely there is a reasonable way.  There might even be existing libraries for this.  The most important question IMO is what skill level are your users?  Do they have experience with any query language?

Comment: I will have to assume that the users are not skilled in any query language. But I believe enough documentation and some examples should bridge that gap. I'm curious to know what kind of libraries are available out there.

Answer (score 6):

Don't `eval()` unless the user is entirely trusted. Instead, implement a simple language for such conditionals.

For example, we can define a data model that represents the structure of a logical expression and can be evaluated on a dictionary:

```py
class Operator:
  def evaluate(self, context: dict) -> bool:
    raise NotImplementedError()

@dataclass
class OpEq(Operator):
  variable: str
  value: object

  def evaluate(self, context: dict) -> bool:
    return context.get(self.variable) == self.value

@dataclass
class OpAnd(Operator):
  clauses: list[Operator]

  def evaluate(self, context: dict) -> bool:
    return all(c.evaluate(context) for c in self.clauses)

@dataclass
class OpOr(Operator):
  clauses: list[Operator]

  def evaluate(self, context: dict) -> bool:
    return any(c.evaluate(context) for c in self.clauses)
```

For example, the expression `(type = "a" OR type = "b") AND val3="off"` would correspond to the objects:

```py
predicate = OpAnd([
  OpOr([
    OpEq("type", "a"),
    OpEq("type", "b"),
  ]),
  OpEq("val3", "off"),
])
```

Next, we can write a parser that handles such expressions. There are many ways to write parsers. The following uses a “recursive descent” approach, i.e. just spells out a parser by hand. Note that the parsing functions have the structure `(offset) -> (value, offset)`.

```py
class InvalidSyntax(Exception):
  def __init__(self, message: str, input: str, offset: int) -> None:
    super().__init__(message, input, offset)
    self.message = message
    self.input = input
    self.offset = offset

  def __str__(self):
    # format a nice error message that points to the error location
    return f"{self.message}\n|{self.input}\n|{'^':>{self.offset+1}}"


RE_VAR = re.compile(r"\b(\w+)\b")
RE_KW_OR = re.compile(r"\bOR\b")
RE_KW_AND = re.compile(r"\bAND\b")
RE_INT = re.compile(r"\b([0-9]+)\b")
RE_STR = re.compile(r'"([^"]*)"')  # could be extended to cover escaping
RE_SPACE = re.compile(r"\s+")

class Parser:
  def __init__(self, input: str) -> None:
    self.input = input

  @classmethod
  def parse(cls, input: str) -> Operator:
    parser = cls(input)
    op, i = parser.parse_logical(0)
    if i != len(input):
      raise parser.error(i, "expected end of expression")
    return op

  def parse_logical(self, i: int) -> Tuple[Operator, int]:
    """Parse `a OR b OR …` or `a AND b AND …` chains"""
    op, i = self.parse_comparison(i)
    i = self.skip_space(i)

    # look ahead to see if this is an AND-chain or OR-chain
    op_type: Callable[[list[Operator]], Operator]
    if RE_KW_AND.match(self.input, i):
      separator = RE_KW_AND
      op_type = OpAnd
    elif RE_KW_OR.match(self.input, i):
      separator = RE_KW_OR
      op_type = OpOr
    else:
      return op, i  # no logical operator

    # parse the entire chain
    clauses = [op]
    while m := separator.match(self.input, i):
      i = self.skip_space(m.end())
      op, i = self.parse_comparison(i)
      clauses.append(op)
      try:
        i = self.skip_space(i)
      except InvalidSyntax:
        break
    return op_type(clauses), i

  def parse_comparison(self, i: int) -> Tuple[Operator, int]:
    """parse `var = value` comparisons and parenthesized expressions"""
    if self.input.startswith("(", i):
      return self.parse_parens(i)

    if m := RE_VAR.match(self.input, i):
      var = m.group(1)
      i = m.end()
    else:
      raise self.error(i, "expected variable name")

    i = self.skip_space(i)
    if self.input.startswith("=", i):
      i += 1
      op_type = OpEq
    else:
      raise self.error(i, "expected: =")
    i = self.skip_space(i)

    value: object
    if m := RE_INT.match(self.input, i):
      value = int(m.group(1))
      i = m.end()
    elif m := RE_STR.match(self.input, i):
      value = m.group(1)
      i = m.end()
    else:
      raise self.error(i, "expected int or quoted string")

    return op_type(var, value), i

  def parse_parens(self, i: int) -> Tuple[Operator, int]:
    """parse a parenthesized expression (...)"""
    if not self.input.startswith("(", i):
      raise self.error(i, "expected: (")

    i = self.skip_space(i)
    op, i = self.parse_logical(i + 1)
    i = self.skip_space(i)

    if not self.input.startswith(")", i):
      raise self.error(i, "expected: )")
    return op, i + 1

  def skip_space(self, i: int) -> int:
    if m := RE_SPACE.match(self.input, i):
      return m.end()
    return i

  def error(self, i, message) -> InvalidSyntax:
    return InvalidSyntax(message, self.input, i)
```

This parser will produce somewhat nice error messages, for example:

```py
>>> Parser.parse('(type = "a" OR type = "b" AND val3="off"')
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
test.InvalidSyntax: expected: )
|(type = "a" OR type = "b" AND val3="off"
|                          ^
```

This is of course a lot of boilerplate. Instead of writing a parser by hand, it would be possible to e.g. use a parser combinator library like parsec:

```py
import parsec as p

def parse(input: str) -> Operator:
  return logical.parse_strict(input)

string = p.regex(RE_STR).parsecmap(lambda s: s[1:-1])
integer = p.regex(RE_INT).parsecmap(int)

@p.generate
def compare_eq():
    variable = yield p.regex(RE_VAR)
    yield p.spaces()
    yield p.string("=")
    yield p.spaces()
    value = yield string | integer
    return OpEq(variable, value)

@p.generate
def parenthesized():
    yield p.string("(")
    yield p.spaces()
    expr = yield logical
    yield p.spaces()
    yield p.string(")")
    return expr

comparison = parenthesized | compare_eq

@p.generate
def logical():
    op = yield comparison << p.spaces()
    chain_type = yield p.optional(
        p.lookahead(
            p.regex(RE_KW_AND).result((RE_KW_AND, OpAnd))
            | p.regex(RE_KW_OR).result((RE_KW_OR, OpOr))))
    if not chain_type:
        return op
    separator, op_type = chain_type
    clauses = yield p.many1(
        p.spaces() >> p.regex(separator) >> p.spaces() >> comparison)
    return op_type([op, *clauses])
```

This is a bit more declarative, but TBH Python is not a good language for techniques like combinator parsing that originate from functional programming. I tend to prefer writing parsers by hand since it's easier to reason about performance characteristics and to produce good error messages.

If you already have a syntax that fits your needs, you might be able to reuse a parser. For example, Python ships with the `ast` module that can parse Python expressions. Once that is done, we only have to convert the Python AST to our data model. For example:

```py
def convert_logical(node: ast.AST) -> Operator:
    if isinstance(node, ast.Expression):
        return convert_logical(node.body)

    if isinstance(node, ast.BoolOp):
        if isinstance(node.op, ast.And):
            return OpAnd([convert_logical(n) for n in node.values])
        if isinstance(node.op, ast.Or):
            return OpOr([convert_logical(n) for n in node.values])

    elif isinstance(node, ast.Compare):
        if len(node.ops) == 1 and isinstance(node.ops[0], ast.Eq):
            name = node.left
            [value] = node.comparators
            assert isinstance(name, ast.Name)
            assert isinstance(value, ast.Constant)
            return OpEq(name.id, value.value)

    raise InvalidSyntax("unsupported syntax", input, node.col_offset)

predicate = convert_logical(ast.parse(expression, mode="eval"))
```

This is very powerful, but limits you to an exact subset of the Python syntax – no syntax customizations are possible, you can only change how the syntax is interpreted. If the user input is untrusted, I would also be worried that this approach exposes a lot of attack surface (but Python's parser is probably much better tested than a hand-written one).

Incidentally, this approach is used by the Pandas library to support queries on dataframes. Uses like `df.query("foo < 3")` are parsed as Python syntax, but usually not evaluated as Python code. Instead, the operations are directly translated to queries on the dataframe. Here, the query would select all rows where the `foo` column is less-than 3.

<sup>Source code for this answer is available at https://gist.github.com/latk/3fa19e3c5ac0564b11539def09aed1e8</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! It will take a while for me to figure out what's happening here and test out few scenarios. I'm surprised that there are no libraries out there which implements such a feature. How about converting the code you've written into a library?

Comment: @najeem I was a bit nerd-sniped by this topic because I like writing parsers. I updated with an example of using Python's built-in `ast` module. I don't want to write a library because I wouldn't use it myself, but feel free to use my code in the linked gist under an Apache-2.0 license.

Comment: I can see that you're interested in this topic! As you said, the ast does expose a lot of attack surface. I am tempted to use the pandas query operation than spin up my own filtering language (copied from your code of course). I hope someone capable than me and have similar need finds your code and build a library.

Comment: One some more exploring, I see that there have been similar attempts in JSON. https://stackoverflow.com/q/777455/3679377. May be a python wrapper for them should work.

ps: I dont understand why all the down votes for this question though!

Comment: I too am looking for a way to allow the user to filter records in a python dictionary using simple and intuitive conditionals such as those supported by the Pandas query(). I would use Pandas dataframes in my case, however my program requires iterative processing of each row in the resulting query which is [discouraged in dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas). Because I am effectively selecting records from a database, I considered MySQL, but that is overkill for my case. @amon's solution for dictionaries would be great.